# Gradle could not resolve org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4-jdbc4

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, spring-boot, gradle

My team is migrating the database to PostgreSQL, but when I try to update the project into my eclipse, there is an error.

Summarizing, the gradle dependence is like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4-jdbc4")
}
```

When I try to build, appears this error: Could not resolve: org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4-jdbc4

Someone knows what I need to do??? My other friend is using normally in her computer, we are using the STS (Spring Tools Suite, a modified Eclipse Version)

Comment: It doesn't exist in Maven central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22. Use a version which exists.

Comment: I've changed to another version in this website and now its working! Thanks!!